# Troubleshooting "fork/exec /usr/bin/ssh: operation not permitted" when running a Docker command within a docker container on AWS Lambda

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, aws-lambda

I have a Docker image that I use as a build server to build a Docker image for my web application.

Running Docker inside Docker is not trivial because most PAAS won't allow privileged mode. But I have a Docker daemon running on EC2 and I use that daemon in my build server using the `DOCKER_HOST` env param (using a PEM to secure the connection). It's been working nicely for about a year.

Now I'd like to run it on Lambda. A big difference is that Lambda makes everything read only except `/tmp`. I use `docker version` to verify the connection. When my build script gets to this command, it fails:

```
> DOCKER_HOST=ssh://foo@12.34.56.78 docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.1
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.19.5
 Git commit:        a5ee5b1
 Built:             Thu Feb  9 19:46:56 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
error during connect: Get "http://docker.example.com/v1.24/version": fork/exec /usr/bin/ssh: operation not permitted
```

In that build server, there's no problem running ssh directly:

```
> /usr/bin/ssh foo@12.34.56.78 pwd
/home/ubuntu
> which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
> echo $(whoami)
sbx_user1051
```

It seems like Docker is either trying to write to the read-only file system, or maybe docker doesn't have permission to run the ssh command? Permissions are not my strong suit, so I've spent days trying these types of commands from other websites. I'm doing this in my Dockerfile for the build server:

```
RUN chmod 777 /root
RUN chmod 777 /usr
RUN chmod 777 -R /root
RUN chmod 777 -R /usr
RUN groupadd docker
RUN usermod -aG docker $USER
RUN usermod -aG docker sbx_user1051
RUN newgrp docker
RUN chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

*Note: I understand these are dangerous permissions. Just trying to get it to work, then I'll back it off appropriately.*

I'm at a dead end, cause I don't know how to troubleshoot this any further. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your first invocation, did you misspell `DOCKER_HOST` with an `H` in "Docker"?  Does the actual error message say `docker.example.com` or is that a placeholder in the question?

Comment: Thanks David - just fixed that typo (it was correct in the code). The error does actually say "docker.example.com" which seemed bizarre to me